# Pandas: Cast/Pivot Multiple Columns from long to wide?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to reconfigure my data from long to wide based on multiple columns. I am generally familiar with the cast function (from R) and the pivot function, but neither is getting me the desired result.

Please see below - The Current table is what I have currently:

```
d = {'Name': ['Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Jerry','Jerry','Jerry','Jerry'], 'col2': ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
     'Result':[10,5,9,2,0,1,10,2,4,5],'Change:':[8,8,4,4,3,3,0,0,8,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Then the Intermediate table pictured is the wide data I desire, where I group by **both** Name and Date and then make the Result column the values. For each Name-Date, there is only one Change result - so the only column I need to make wide is Type.

The last step is to calculate the r^2 values for each Name-Date for both Types A and B. That is the Output table.

I have tried to use the [cast function](https://sandipanweb.wordpress.com/2017/11/11/some-data-processing-and-analysis-with-python/) per below, as well as the pivot function. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
zz_cast=cast(df,'Type','Result(%)')
zz_pivot=df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Type', values='Result (%)')
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please add date to a piece of code where you construct the data?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to create your intermediate table (wide data):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d = {'Name': ['Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Jerry','Jerry','Jerry','Jerry'], 
 'Date': ['2018/07/31','2018/07/31','2018/04/30','2018/04/30','2018/01/31','2018/01/31','2018/10/31','2018/10/31','2018/07/31','2018/07/31'], 
 'Type': ['A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B','A','B'],
 'Result':[10,5,9,2,0,1,10,2,4,5],'Change:':[8,8,4,4,3,3,0,0,8,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.set_index(['Name','Date','Type']).unstack().reset_index()
```